# Vue.js: Element is shown for a moment despite of conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, conditional-statements, conditional-rendering

I have a navigation with a button which toggle a menu and a button of signin.

When a user is not authorised, he can see only SignIn button. When the user is signed in, that button disappears and he/she can see a hamburger button which toggle the user's menu.

I have a condition based on the attribute `isLoaded` which can be false or true depenending on API response (is profile data loaded or not which happens after signin). It works properly but the button SignIn appears for a moment when I reload the page and after redirect to the main page after signin process. I wonder how I can avoid this.

I suspect that this button is shown while the app is waiting for API response and as soon as it sees `isLoaded: true`, it hides the button after checking the condition.

Here is my code:

```
<v-toolbar app fixed dark color="light-blue lighten-2">
  <user-nav-button v-if="getProfile.isLoaded"
                   @toggle-drawer="$refs.drawer.drawer = !$refs.drawer.drawer" />
  <v-toolbar-title v-if="getProfile.isLoaded">
    <router-link :to="{ name: '/' }"
                 class="white--text" >
      APP
    </router-link>
  </v-toolbar-title>
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'login' }"
               class="sign-in-button"
               v-if="!getProfile.isLoaded">
    SIGNIN
  </router-link>
</v-toolbar>
<profile-sidebar v-if="getProfile.isLoaded"
                 ref="drawer" />

<script>
export default {
data() {
 return {
  drawer: '',
 };
},
components: {
  UserNavButton,
  ProfileSidebar,
  MainFooter,
 },
 created() {
  this.loadProfile();
 },
 computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['getProfile']),
 },
 methods: {
  ...mapActions(['loadProfile']),
 },
};
<script>
```

My store:

```
export default {
 state: {
 profile: {
  isLoaded: false,
  data: [],
  },
},
actions: {
 loadProfile({ commit }) {
  if (config.token !== '') {
    http
      .post('api')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        commit('SET_PROFILE', data);
      });
  }
 },
},
mutations: {
 SET_PROFILE(state, data) {
  state.profile = {
    isLoaded: true,
    data,
  };
 },
},
getters: {
 getProfile(state) {
  return state.profile;
  },
 },
};
```

Comment: Just have a default value for the `getProfile.isLoaded`. So while it waits for the data, you have a default one where element is now shown.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This attribute already has default value of `false`. It is toggled to `true` when I create an action which has a mutation. This mutation toggles `isLoaded` to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is doing exactly what you're telling it to.

```
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'login' }"
               class="sign-in-button"
               v-if="!getProfile.isLoaded">
```

When `getProfile.isLoaded` is false, you're showing it. And that is also your default state.

Personally I would decouple the `isloaded` from the profile data. Use a `loadingfinished` data property (or `$store` property)

What you really want is to show that button only when two conditions are met:

1. loading is finished
2. you know that the user is NOT signed in.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I added my code from store. Unfortunately, this solution didn't change anything for me. :(

Comment: @OlgaB Your store code looks fine. How are you calling that in your view component methods?

Comment: @OlgaB - I edited my answer, based on your code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise. I marked this as a solution, however I preferred to create a method in main.js where I check whether I have a token or not. Then I used v-if directives based on this method. It works perfectly fine. :)

Comment: You're welcome. A method for checking sounds more thorough than what I show here - but for other readers on StackOverflow a simple answer like mine is better. Devs can always complicate things on their own.